# Many to many relationship identity error

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, many-to-many, entity-framework-5

I'm working on a mvc4 app with ef5 codefirst and I cannot solve this error:

The member with identity 'xxxx' does not exist in the metadata collection.

**Update:**
I saw that I used two different contexts (the navigation object was called thorugh a repository that creates a different DbContext), probably this is a problem. I changed that, but now I get a new error:

> Invalid column name 'Brewery_BreweryId'.

In the IntelliTrace I saw that ef tries to

```
select ..., Brewery_BreweryId from UserProfiles
```

This column is not present and shouldn't be present, I want a many to many, not a one-to-many.

I think that is something related to a many to many relation.

this is an example of my code

```
internal class BreweryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Brewery>
{
    public BreweryConfiguration()
    {
      // PK
      HasKey(e => e.BreweryId);

      // FK
      HasMany(e => e.UserProfiles)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(m =>
        {
          m.MapLeftKey("BreweryId");
          m.MapRightKey("UserId");
          m.ToTable("BreweryUserProfiles");
        });

    namespace Project2.DAL.Entities
    {
      [Table("Breweries")]
      public class Brewery : ABrewery
      {
        public int BreweryId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
      }
    }

    namespace Project1.DAL.Entities
    {
      [Table("UserProfiles")]
      public class UserProfile : IUserProfile
      {

        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        ...
      }
}
```

[image: Join table]

Answer (score 1):

```
c.MapLeftKey("ClassB_ID");
c.MapRightKey("ClassA_ID");
```

should be

```
c.MapLeftKey("ClassA_ID");
c.MapRightKey("ClassB_ID");
```

Edit:

You need to define the PK of the ClassB in the configuration as well. In the way you implemented, you may add another derived Configuration for ClassB.

Comment: I tried, I've also tried to delete the tables and recreate everything from the scratch .. I tried to remove the map and let EF to do the job for me .. I'm getting always the same error. If needed, I can post more code.

Comment: I updated the post with more informations .. if you can help me, I'll really appreciate 'cause I'm going crazy with this :S